# How to make regex grouping find all occurrences?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, regex-group

I'm using the mod_rewrite module.

I want to preserve all query parameters that starts with the characters 'a_' and discard all others. I'm using regex grouping '()', but I'm unable to match multiple query parameters.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "(a_[a-zA-Z]+=[a-zA-Z]+)"
RewriteRule "(.*)" "$1?%0" [S=1] #Append grouped query params and skip next line
RewriteRule "(.*)" "$1?"
```

https://www.regextester.com/?fam=111092

a_foo=bar&b_bar=baz&a_qux=quux

%1 = a_foo=bar 
%2 = a_qux=quux 
%0 = a_foo=bara_qux=quux

Comment: GET "example.com?a_foo=bar&b_bar=baz"
REDIRECT "example.com?a_foo=bar"

Comment: Do you want to remove all query parameters that are not starting with `a_` ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove all parameters recursively that start with a_
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)a_ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?(?!a_)[^=&]+=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [DPI,N,E=QS:1]

# perform a redirect in the end
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_QS} =1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)(?!a_) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: It did not work.

https://example.com/?a_bar=bar&b_bar=bar

Redirects to:
https://example.com/?a_bar=bar&b_bar=bar (identical)

Comment: What is your Apache version? Also test with only this code in site root .htaccess. These rules work fine for me on my local Apache.